# Cannot launch AVD in Emulator

Tags: haxm

**Emulator:**

> ERROR :X86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
>   please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable
>   CPU acceleration status: HAX kernel module is not installed

**My processor details:**

iNtel  Core 2 Duo E7500 @ 2.93GH   32 Bit
with intel VT enabled and DEP enabled

I am using Windows XP sp2

How can I solve this error?

Comment: Did you install HAXM? It's in `extras/intel/Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager` of the android SDK

Comment: it does not get installed while installing it tells unable to open driver ......

Comment: You may be out of luck then, [it may need at least Windows 7](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager) based on the information page.